# PHP & MySQL question

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering how can I stop an empty value from being entered into my MySQL database in the example below which will enter nothing in to the database, so that my MySQL Default NULL value is displayed in the database?

```
if(empty($_POST['username'])){
    $u = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$u='NULL'
```

then your SQL query could be

```
UPDATE myTable(user) INSERT user=$u WHERE id='12345';
```

Don't forget to sanitize the data you received from the user!

Comment: You'll need a primary key to find unique rows. If this is the username, then yes, it should be unique - and you should not be inserting NULL values in a primary key.  In my example, I used `id` as the unique (primary key) field, so the username can be non-unique.

Comment: But having a non-unique username in any case would surely be a bad idea! A username would have to be unique by definition so that it identified only one user.

Comment: @Mark - yes, usually, but not always.  SO, for example, allows non-unique usernames: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62708/two-identical-usernames

Comment: @Steve, its not a PRIMARY KEY its a UNIQUE KEY that needs a to have a NULL value some times.

Comment: This all depends on your design. Primary keys should never be null. Unique keys can have one null. The rest is up to you.

Comment: @Steve, By my understanding can't UNIQUE KEYS have more the one NULL value as there DEFAULT?